# How to start SQL Server job from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-job

How can I create a stored procedure to start a SQL Server job?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can execute the stored procedure `sp_start_job` in *your* stored procedure.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

Answer (score 18):

```
-- Create SQL Server Agent job start stored procedure with input parameter
CREATE PROC uspStartMyJob @MyJobName sysname
AS
DECLARE @ReturnCode tinyint -- 0 (success) or 1 (failure)
EXEC @ReturnCode=msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=@MyJobName;
RETURN (@ReturnCode)
GO
```

OR with no parameter:

```
-- Create stored procedure to start SQL Server Agent job
CREATE PROC StartMyMonthlyInventoryJob
AS
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Monthly Inventory Processing';
GO
-- Execute t-sql stored procedure
EXEC StartMyMonthlyInventoryJob
```

EDIT FYI: You can use this PRIOR to starting IF you don't want to start the job IF it is running currently, work this in your stored proc:

```
-- Get run status of a job
-- version for SQL Server 2008 T-SQL - Running = 1 = currently executing
 -- use YOUR guid here
DECLARE @job_id uniqueidentifier = '5d00732-69E0-2937-8238-40F54CF36BB1' 
EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, sa, @job_id
```

Answer (score 7):

Create your store procedure and run the job inside your proc as follows:

```
DECLARE @JobId binary(16)
SELECT @JobId = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = 'JobName')

IF (@JobId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @JobId;
END
```