# Submit long-running SQL query from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have an ASP.NET web application that needs to submit a long running SQL stored procedure with parameters. It could run up to 30 minutes. How can I submit to run on the sql server as a job so the web app can continue on with something else? Is it possible to check if the job is finished from ASP.NET?

Comment: You can use an async method and the await keyword.

Comment: I usually create a backgroundworker and put sql iinto the backgroundworker.  The SQL Server command with SQL.CMD which is a commnad line query to database.  I often create a process to run SQL.CMD and put results into a csv file.  Then later read csv file into c#.  SQL.CMD is more efficient than running a query through c# interface.

Comment: read about Quartz.NET or HangFire

Comment: I thought it would be better to run as a sql job because it would continue to run even if the user shut down the browser or the app pool recycled.

Comment: A possible solution is to look at [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/) Although long running tasks in IIS are problematic due to AppPool recycling.

Comment: You would probably be better served decoupling these long running processes from your application. One option would be to queue up a sql job, however, if this is going to be a common occurrence in your organization or application then you may want to look into a service type application built specifically to handle your common occurrences on a regular basis. That way you could just query a log table to see when the next occurrence of your "service job" will run and what the last result was.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by putting the query into a job.  Then the page/website would check back to see if the job is complete.

Start a Job
[How to start SQL Server job from a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906923/how-to-start-sql-server-job-from-a-stored-procedure)

Check Status of Job
[How can I determine the status of a job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200195/how-can-i-determine-the-status-of-a-job)